# Send newrelic application name

Tags: java, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I'm using newrelic java agent,
I'm sending informarion to newrelic insights from my java app.
how to send also newrelic application name (exist in newrelic.yml) so that
I can know which application is sending the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I open a discussion with newrelic support

https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/how-to-get-app-name-from-my-application/49366

Support answer:

The application name should automatically be included in all Transaction events from APM apps under the appName attribute. You can include additional custom attributes - such as the number of users - in Transaction events by calling the agent API as outlined here: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/manage-apm-agents/agent-data/collect-custom-attributes#enabling-custom.

For example, in Java:

```
NewRelic.addCustomParameter("numberOfUsers", numberOfUsers);
```